# Page loading window with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I found this tip http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/loader.html, but when i trying to use it i receive

> TypeError: $.mobile.loading is not a function

Have any ideas?

Comment: @AnkurMittal   $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
 text: 'foo',
 textVisible: true,
 theme: 'z',
 html: ""
}); as in example

Answer (score 1):

The example you are mentioning refers to an older jQuery mobile version.

As stated in the current [jQuery Mobile Doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html), the equivalent method is:

> $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg (method)
>
> Arguments:
>
> - theme (string, default: "a") The theme swatch for the message.
> - msgText (string, default: "loading") The text of the message.
> - textonly (boolean, default: false) If true, the "spinner" image will be hidden when the message is shown.